# Get all child elements of Tpagecontrols

Tags: delphi

I have a page control on my form. This page control has two or three tabs. Each tab has a few other controls like button, label panel etc. I am able to find all controls but if some control sits on top of the panel, then I am unable to find that control

My code:

```
for I := 0 to Pagecontrol.Pagecount -1 do
begin
  for J := 0 to pagecontrol.pages[i].controlcount - 1 do
    showmessage(pagecontrol.pages[i].controls[J].name) // not able to find button whose parent is panel
end
```

and when i do

```
for J := 0 to pagecontrol.pages[i].componentscount- 1 do  // it does not enter into loop
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Controls[]` property lists the immediate children. You need to drill down to the children of the children and so on. Typically that is done recursively like this:

```
procedure WalkChildren(Parent: TWinControl; Visit: TProc<TControl>);
var
  i: Integer;    
  Child: TControl;
begin
  for i := 0 to Parent.ControlCount-1 do 
  begin
    Child := Parent.Controls[i];
    Visit(Child);
    if Child is TWinControl then 
      WalkChildren(TWinControl(Child), Visit);
  end;
end;
```

You might call this like so:

```
for i := 0 to PageControl1.PageCount-1 do
  WalkChildren(
    PageControl1.Pages[i], 
    procedure(Child: TControl) 
    begin 
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Child.Name); 
    end
  );
```

Or even:

```
WalkChildren(
  PageControl1, 
  procedure(Child: TControl) 
  begin 
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Child.Name); 
  end
```